# Importing openzeppelin-test-helpers

Tags: truffle, truffle-test, openzeppelin

Somethings I need BN library for correct balanceOf assertion with 1e18 decimals, somettimes expectRevert. I see the different projects use it differently:

```
const { constants, time, ether, expectRevert } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
```

or

```
const { BN, constants, expectEvent, expectRevert } = require('openzeppelin-test-helpers');
```

is there any difference?

Comment: If your package.json file has `"@openzeppelin/test-helpers"`, then you should use the first option.

Comment: If your package.json file has `"openzeppelin-test-helpers"`, then you should use the second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const { constants, time, ether, expectRevert } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
```

This is the modern way of importing trusted NPM packages. The other way must be some old legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

You should `require` whatever is declared in your `package.json` file.

For example:

- If `"openzeppelin-test-helpers": "0.5.1"`, then `require('openzeppelin-test-helpers')`
- If `"@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "0.5.9"`, then `require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers')`

In this specific case, since ['openzeppelin-test-helpers' has been renamed to '@openzeppelin/test-helpers'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openzeppelin-test-helpers), you probably want to choose the latter (i.e., declare it in your `package.json` file, and `require` it in your truffle test file).